# Count number of each foreign key in a table with recursive relationship

Tags: sql

I have an issue with my table that has recursive relation. My goal is to count how many times each PK was used as a FK in my table. Here is a scheme:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| ID | Name| BirtDate| Salary | SupervisorID |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

This is an Employee table that has Supervisor which is also an Employee.

I came up with this type of query , but it doesnt work.

```
SELECT Employee.ID, COUNT(Employee.SupervisorID) as Number FROM Employee
left join Employee as emp2 on Employee.ID = emp2.ID
WHERE Employee.SupervisorID = emp2.ID
group by
    Employee.ID
```

My goal would be Something like this:

```
--------------
| ID | Number|
--------------
```

where ID is a PK and Number - how many times it was used as a SupervisorID FK.

Anyone have any ideas how to achieve it ? P.S. I think there suppose to be a while loop in a SQL but not sure.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use.

Comment: Just remove the left join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query counts how many supervisors each employees has, which is one at max.

You could instead use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT
    Employee.ID,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        Employee AS emp2
    WHERE
        emp2.SupervisorID = Employee.ID
    ) as Number
FROM
    Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by statement.    `select E.Id, COUNT(E.Id) from employee E JOIN Employee E2 ON E.Id = E2.SupervisorID
  Group By E.Id`

Answer (score 0):

PLease use the below

```
    SELECT emp1.ID, COUNT(emp1.SupervisorID) as Number1 FROM Employee emp1
    inner join Employee  emp2 on emp1.SupervisorID = emp2.ID
    group by
    emp1.ID
```